# PHP Add array to array with string as key

Tags: php

I have a problem. I am using this code:

```
$sql = "SELECT Id, FileName FROM Templates ORDER BY DateTimeUploaded DESC";

if($result = $conn->query($sql))
{
    if($result->num_rows >= 1) 
    {           
        while($row = $result->fetch_object())
        {
            $arrTotal["Templates"] = array($row);
        }

        $result->free();

    }

    $arrTotal["Source"] = "media/templates/";
    echo json_encode($arrTotal);
}
```

But when I print the json, the `$arrTotal["Templates"]` has only one row, but it has 17 rows.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `$arrTotal["Templates"][] = array($row);` Use double squares to add an entry. This is the shortcut for `array_push()`.

Comment: Yes, like @MarkusZeller said, you overwrite the value. Also, is not neccesary `array($row)`, just `$row` when you add the object to array.

Comment: You could simplify to `if($result->num_rows)`. Because any number not 0 will end in true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You repeatedly assign values to an array member, need add `[]` to avoid this situation:

```
while($row = $result->fetch_object())
{
    $arrTotal["Templates"][] = array($row);
}
```

Comment: Also it's redundant to cast object to array. `fetch_assoc` already fetches array.

Comment: @u_mulder This is no cast from object to array. It is wrapping an object in an array. Casting would look like `(array) $row`. But I agree, it should not be neccessary wrapping the object in an array. So `$arrTotal["Templates"][] = $row;` should be enough.